# Can TikZ be used in a caption block?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I want to get the following effect:

[image]

I wrote the code show below, but itt cannot be compiled. I don't know what is wrong with it, or how to get the effect of Figure 1. What should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, circle, inner sep=0.2pt] {\textbf{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\tikz{ \node [draw, circle, inner sep=0.2pt] {\textbf{1}};} is a node.}
\label{pic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect` before `\tikz` and `\node` helps.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yeah, it works! Would you explain why? Thank you!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Maybe I've known that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragile commands need `\protect` if they are used in moving arguments as in `\caption`. The argument moves to the `.aux` file and from there to the `.lof` file for the list of figures:

```
\caption{\protect\tikz{\protect\node [draw, circle, inner sep=0.2pt] {\textbf{1}};} is a node.}
```

The following example moves the baseline of the node text to the context baseline, defines a robust macro for use of the node in the text or `\caption` and defines a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{bold circled} = [
  circle,
  draw,
  inner sep=0.2pt,
  node font=\bfseries,
]
\DeclareRobustCommand*\BoldCircled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
  \node[bold circled] (X) {#1};%
}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[bold circled] {1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\BoldCircled{1} is a node.}
  \label{pic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]